# Stripe + Firebase Functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, function

I have a reactjs project with firebase, and I'm trying to implement Stripe as a payment method, I uploaded my files in firebase functions but it's not working...

In firebase functions this appears:
[Unable to load some functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M72MK.png)

When I click on the link that firebase functions gave me this appears...[firebase functions link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUi5N.png)

My functions files are these:
index.js:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = require("./server");

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

server.js (This file was given to me by the stripe when creating the webhook):

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./firebase-adminsdk-by954.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();


const stripe = require('stripe')('MY-STRIPE-SECRET-KEY');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


const endpointSecret = "MY-ENDPOINT-SECRET";

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const fulfillOrder = async (session) => {
  console.log("Fulfilling order", session);
  try{

    const customer = await stripe.customers.update(
      session.customer,
      {metadata: 
        {'firebase_uid': session.client_reference_id}
      }
    );

    await db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(session.client_reference_id)
    .update({
      accType: 'premium',
      premiumTime: session.expires_at
    })
    
  }catch(error){
    console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`)
  }

}

const cancelSubs = async (session) => {

  console.log("UPDATED => ", session);

  try{   

    const customerId = session.customer;

    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
    var userId = await customer.metadata.firebase_uid;

    await db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .update({
      accType: 'free',
      premiumTime: ''
    })

  }catch(error){
    console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`)
  }

}

app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (request, response) => {

  const payload = request.body;
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  switch (event.type) {

    case 'checkout.session.completed': {

      const checkoutSessionCompleted = event.data.object;
      
      if (checkoutSessionCompleted.payment_status === 'paid') {
        fulfillOrder(checkoutSessionCompleted);
      }

      break;
    }

    case 'customer.subscription.deleted': {

      const customerSubscriptionPaused = event.data.object;

      cancelSubs(customerSubscriptionPaused);

    }
  }

  response.status(200).end();
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));

module.exports = app;
```

On the stripe dashboard (status code 403):

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/app</code> from this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

```
{
  "id": "evt_1NbonMFO4yyekLj6ao3Pb7ue",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1691258504,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a16NCZo6jiooR3WPegxK76jHn1AW2VkeJGSysDLtshtVYRJcjZZbIgXZ5w",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "after_expiration": null,
      "allow_promotion_codes": false,
      "amount_subtotal": 3490,
      "amount_total": 3490,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": "auto",
      "cancel_url": "https://stripe.com",
      "client_reference_id": "UBWLQ2X12Obv9aadF40SpLPf13J3",
      "consent": null,
      "consent_collection": {
        "promotions": "none",
        "terms_of_service": "none"
      },
      "created": 1691258493,
      "currency": "brl",
      "currency_conversion": null,
      "custom_fields": [
      ],
      "custom_text": {
        "shipping_address": null,
        "submit": null
      },
      "customer": "cus_OOc1Wi6qxkPb4W",
      "customer_creation": "always",
      "customer_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "BR",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "my-email@hotmail.com",
        "name": "tests",
        "phone": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": "my-email@hotmail.com",
      "expires_at": 1691344893,
      "invoice": "in_1NbonKFO4yyekLj66QD6B2fb",
      "invoice_creation": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": "en",
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "subscription",
      "payment_intent": null,
      "payment_link": null,
      "payment_method_collection": "always",
      "payment_method_options": null,
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "phone_number_collection": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "recovered_from": null,
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "shipping_cost": null,
      "shipping_details": null,
      "shipping_options": [
      ],
      "status": "complete",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": "sub_1NbonKFO4yyekLj6JI78DVLH",
      "success_url": "https://stripe.com",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 3,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

I couldn't quote everything I tried, I tried several alternatives with chatGPT, and always the same thing